# Static route removes another static route

Tags: routing, router, vyos, static

In the following diagram each Vyos router has RIP configure and R1 has NAT to allow hosts from 10.0.0.0/24 and 192.168.10.0/24 accessing the internet. The goal is to put the PCs comunicating with each other.
From inside of the firewall to outside it's made because Pfsense is routing. From outside, I thought to define a static route in R1 with the following comand:

```
#set protocol static route 192.168.10.0/24 next-hop 10.0.0.50
```

However the static route that allowed the hosts connecting the internet desappear. The folowing line,

```
 S>* 0.0.0.0/0 [210/0] via 10.0.2.2, eth0, weight 1, 00:00:59
```

was replace by,

```
S> 192.168.10.0/24 [1/0] via 10.0.0.50 (recursive), weight 1, 00:00:10
```

Can you help me to understand what is happening?. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If would help if you would show what command you're using to check routing. Are you looking up a specific route, or are you listing the entire routing table?

Comment: @TeunVink the command that I use to see the routes is the  `show ip route` . Initial I wanted to see the entire routing table to check if a specific route was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #set protocol static route 192.168.10.0/24 next-hop 10.0.0.50

That can't work. 10.0.0.50 isn't connected to R1. Possibly, it just falls back that route to the default route - what exactly happens escapes me.

Instead: on R1, you'd need to route 192.168.10.0/24 via R3 (10.0.0.57) and on R3 via PfSense (10.0.0.50).

RIP should also be able to handle it if you just set it up on R3, but it's been 15+ years since I've worked with RIP...

Comment: When I set the static route for the network 192.168.10.0/24 on R1 through R3, the default route to the outside disappears.  I have to set eth0 interface with dhcp again, so that the default route activates again. I think it must be a Vyos issue. Thank you for the help.